# How to merge image and audio to video with the same color ? (FFMPEG)

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, wav, flac, mkv

i try to merge audio and image to video in ffmpeg,

The problem that export does not have the same color as the original

---

**Here is a comparison on YouTube**

Original : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsSBI9qwFE4

Export ffmpeg : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsxwqTSqpbQ

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i rose.jpg -i rose.flac -c copy -shortest rose.mkv
```

I want to get the same color as my original image

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the color?

Comment: Color looks the same to me in Firefox on Linux.

Comment: You're right the color is same in firefox, but not in google chrome, why ?